# How to remove Unicode symbol from Vietnamese string in C#

Tags: c#, unicode

I am doing a project for my partner in VietNam and i have to solve Vietnamese.
How to remove all Unicode symbols in Vietnamese string?

Eg: Xin chào các bạn! (hello every body) --> Xin chao cac ban!

Comment: You can try to use UTF16 for this. The idea is to transform the string to UTF16. You will get two bytes for each character. One byte is 'decoration' like accents etc. the other should plain character. I'm not a C# expert but I have done similar trick in PHP some time ago.

Comment: Thanks! That is good idea. But i think TonyBui's solution is nice work.

Comment: @Adam No that's not the case. Where did you get that from?

Comment: @AdwardFriday That's a bit like removing all vowels from English text. Mb y cn stll rd t bt t's nt gng t b s.

Comment: @roeland I don't know Vietnamese and I was removing diacritics in other language that way. You say that you just can't do that in Vietnamese? So is the whole question a misunderstanding?

Comment: @Adam I don't know Vietnamese either, but judging from the amount of diacritics it's removing a lot of information. Maybe/probably Vietnamese speakers will still be able to read that—ask your partner—but I'd expect it to look quite weird. I'd say if you're doing a project over there it's worth it to properly support Unicode.

Comment: I'm Vietnamese and I'm sure that TonyBui's solution is clearer than using generic accent removes, as I already looked for generic and still stucked in some specific chars like "Đ", "đ"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a `string[]` `VietnameseSigns` contains all Vietnamese signs.

Eg:

```
private static readonly string[] VietnameseSigns = new string[]
        {

            "aAeEoOuUiIdDyY",

            "áàạảãâấầậẩẫăắằặẳẵ",

            "ÁÀẠẢÃÂẤẦẬẨẪĂẮẰẶẲẴ",

            "éèẹẻẽêếềệểễ",

            "ÉÈẸẺẼÊẾỀỆỂỄ",

            "óòọỏõôốồộổỗơớờợởỡ",

            "ÓÒỌỎÕÔỐỒỘỔỖƠỚỜỢỞỠ",

            "úùụủũưứừựửữ",

            "ÚÙỤỦŨƯỨỪỰỬỮ",

            "íìịỉĩ",

            "ÍÌỊỈĨ",

            "đ",

            "Đ",

            "ýỳỵỷỹ",

            "ÝỲỴỶỸ"
        };
```

After that, you define a function to remove all Vietnamese signs from input string.

Eg:

```
public static string RemoveSign4VietnameseString(string str)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < VietnameseSigns.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < VietnameseSigns[i].Length; j++)
                    str = str.Replace(VietnameseSigns[i][j], VietnameseSigns[0][i - 1]);
            }
            return str;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use [Diacritics](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Diacritics/) package to remove the symbol, you can check it from the link that I pin it